# DropzoneJS - How to show uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, scripting, dropzone.js

How do dropzoneJS to view files that were already uploaded? 
I followed the steps of documentation and the uploading is working, but is not showing the files already uploaded.

Thanks for the support

HTML form code:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            $("#my-dropzone").dropzone({
                //url: "/file/post",
                addRemoveLinks : true,
                maxFilesize: 0.5,
                dictResponseError: 'Erro ao fazer o upload !'
            });
        })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">     
        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            init: function() {
                thisDropzone = this;                    
                $.get('upload.php', function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key,value){
                        var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };                           
                        thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);             
                        thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "uploads/"+value.name);                          
                    });                      
                });
            }
        };
</script>
```

Code - upload.php:

```
<?php

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = 'uploads';  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

   $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 
   $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 
   move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

} else { 

  $result  = array(); 
  $files = scandir($storeFolder);                  
  if ( false!==$files ) {
    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
        if ( '.'!=$file && '..'!=$file) {       
            $obj['name'] = $file;
            $obj['size'] = filesize($storeFolder.$ds.$file);
            $result[] = $obj;
        }
    }
}
    header('Content-type: text/json');              
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: `init`: "is a function that gets called when Dropzone is initialized. You can setup event listeners inside this function." (From http://www.dropzonejs.com/) Looks like your firing an AJAX call when dropzone is initialized, in other words, no files are loaded. Also, how does your AJAX get the files ready for upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handler to "queuecomplete" of the dropzone. In this handler, make a call to another function that load images.

This is my example code for loading uploaded images and reset the upload form.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    init: function(){
        var th = this;
        this.on('queuecomplete', function(){
            ImageUpload.loadImage();  // CALL IMAGE LOADING HERE
            setTimeout(function(){
                th.removeAllFiles();
            },5000);
        })
    },
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB       
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',

};
```